# Python - all lottery combinations - no duplicates, in order

Tags: python

I've wrote a script to print out lottery combinations. What i'm aiming for is this: There are 6 numbers in the lottery between 1-49 meaning there are 13,983,816 combinations. I want to print out all combinations IN ORDER whilst making sure there are NO duplicates.

Here is my code so far:

```
import random
numbers = []
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(6):
        numbers.append(random.randint(1,49))
        for k in range(j):
            while numbers[j]==numbers[k]:
                numbers[j]=random.randint(1,49)
    print sorted(numbers)
    numbers = []
f = open('combinations.txt', 'w')
f.write(str(sorted(numbers)))
```

The problems are:

The output in the terminal is:

```
[18, 20, 27, 32, 44, 48]
[5, 7, 10, 13, 33, 45]
```

I want to start with `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` and end up at `[44,45,46,47,48,49]`. So I need to order the results.

Also, I've tried converting the list to a string so I can put the results in a big text file, but I'm just printing `[]` to the text file at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were clearing your list **then** writing to the file.

```
from itertools import combinations
f = open('combinations.txt', 'w')
for comb in combinations(range(1,50), 6):
    f.write(str(comb))
    f.write('\n')
f.close()
```

***But** make sure you have at least 350 Megabytes of disk space free!* and some time to spare.

*(348168480 bytes I checked with:*

```
>>> s = 0
>>> for comb in combinations(range(1,50), 6):
...    s += len(repr(comb))+2
... 
>>> s
348168480
```

*).*

Answer (score 8):

Use [`itertools.combinations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> for comb in combinations(range(1,50), 6):
...     print comb      #Hit Enter at your own risk
```

For printing the combinations to the text file:

```
with open('combinations.txt', 'w') as f:
   for comb in combination:
       f.write(str(comb) + '\n')
```

Comment: Wow that's really simple. Thanks Ashwini. Didn't know such a module existed.

Comment: would I need to use a for loop to print all the results to a txt file?

Comment: I want every combination in the text file with each combination on a newline (\n)

Comment: Wouldn't iterating over the results and writing to a file be better than unpacking the iterator? Considering the number of elements is huge!

Comment: @SukritKalra Oops! I totally missed that, a simple for-loop is better.

Comment: `Hit Enter at your own risk`: Printing 49choose6 combinations to screen would take 55865.068640177684 seconds on my machine. That's 15 and a half hours!

Answer (score 0):

```
**import itertools
f= open('combinations.txt','w')
numb = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
it = itertools.combinations(numb,3)
for x in it:
    f.write(str(x))
    f.write('\n')
f.close()**
```

There you go, just add as many numbers to numb and change the it variable to correspondent of r

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
from datetime import timedelta

start_time = time.time()

from itertools import combinations
comb_list = list(combinations(range(1, 50), 6))
start_index = comb_list.index((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
counter = 0

for i, comb in enumerate(comb_list[start_index:]):
    print(f"Combination {i+1}: {comb}")
    counter += 1

end_time = time.time()
elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
elapsed_time = timedelta(seconds=elapsed_time)
print("Elapsed time:", elapsed_time)
```

> #Combination 1: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
> #Combination 13983816: (44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49)
> #Elapsed time: 0:03:33.373467

Comment: In the future please add an explanation for why you're doing what you're doing and what they are doing incorrectly that resulted in the behavior they are seeing

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).